# ftpLib nlst() throwing an error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 87: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8, ftp, lib, directory-listing

I want to list file names in FTP server. I am using the combination of:

```
ftpCon = ftplib.FTP(host=<URL>, user=<username>, passwd=<password>)
```

and listing of file names

```
listOfFiles =  ftpCon.nlst()
```

By debugging I found that listing is failing and it returns  ***'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 87: invalid continuation byte***

Any idea what could be wrong or how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can change the encoding with the `encoding` parameter in `FTP(...)`. Many FTP servers don't use UTF8. Try `latin-1`. If you already know the encoding used by the server, try that

Comment: Or `cp437` (which I think it is more appropriate for FTP: it is a older encoding, used for DOS). You have an error, so it should be relatively easy to find the best encoding (which show the 0xed as intended)

Comment: Thank you very much PanagiotisKanavos, GiacomoCatenazzi. It helps!

Comment: I'm just looking deeper into this. Seems with `utf-8` when doing `ftp.nlst()` it breaks on files with an `é`. These are properly handled with `latin-1` and but the `é` transforms to `Θ` with `cp437` encoding. But `latin-1` AND `cp437` break on names with emojis e.g. 
:|